# Converting inconsistent formatting into time (hour,minute) into cleaner consistent formatting

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, analysis

I am trying to input and manipulate data into python and am having trouble converting a csv into the correct formatting for the row.

I tried printing a row and attempting to search the string using Regex but I'm not too familiar with it.

```
timeNote = ['18.30-19.00', '4PM-5PM', '3-4', '4-4.10PM', '15-18', '15 - 17']
```

I have tried using this

```
for i in range(len(timeNote)):
    print(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', timeNote[i]))
```

it prints this

```
['18', '30', '19', '00']
[]
['3', '4']
['4', '4']
['15', '18']
['15', '17']
```

If there is a better way to even convert to time domain would be appreciated. I'm fairly new to python if it's not already obvious.

Comment: Could you please give us an example of the desired output ?

Comment: there are some uncertainties in your data, would '3-4' be '3AM-4AM' or '3PM-4PM'?

Comment: It's probably 3PM to 4PM.

Comment: Yes something like this,

['10:00', '18:00', '12:00', '09:00', '09:00', '11:00', '10:00']

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `pandas`, here's one approach. Note that you can use the pattern inside `extract` as your regex pattern:

```
timeNote = ['18.30-19.00', '4PM-5PM', '3-4', '4-4.10PM', '15-18', '15 - 17']
s = pd.Series(timeNote)

pattern = '(?P<start>[\d\.]+)(?P<start_pm>PM)?\D*(?P<end>[\d\.]+)(?P<end_pm>PM)?'

s.str.extract(pattern)
```

Output

```
   start start_pm    end end_pm
0  18.30      NaN  19.00    NaN
1      4       PM      5     PM
2      3      NaN      4    NaN
3      4      NaN   4.10     PM
4     15      NaN     18    NaN
5     15      NaN     17    NaN
```

For regex explanation, you can paste the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/).

From there, you can choose to interpret your data. Note that with this form, `start` and `and` are strings.

We can even go crazier and parse the hour and minutes:

```
pattern = ('(?P<s_h>[\d]+)'+  # start hour
           '[.:]?(?P<s_m>\d+)?'+ # start minute
           '(?P<s_pm>PM)?' + # start PM
           '\D*(?P<e_h>\d+)'+ # end hour
           '[.:]?(?P<e_m>\d+)?'+ # end minute
           '(?P<e_pm>PM)?' # end PM
          )

print(s.str.extract(pattern))
```

gives:

```
  s_h  s_m s_pm e_h  e_m e_pm
0  18   30  NaN  19   00  NaN
1   4  NaN   PM   5  NaN   PM
2   3  NaN  NaN   4  NaN  NaN
3   4  NaN  NaN   4   10   PM
4  15  NaN  NaN  18  NaN  NaN
5  15  NaN  NaN  17  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!! How should I go about 24 hour time assuming its 3PM to 4PM?

Comment: You check if the number is less than, say 6, then add 12?

Comment: Cheers man. How should i go about replacing the ends with :00 and replacing the . with a :

Comment: you can do `fillna('00')` on `s_m` and `e_m`.  `s.replace('\.', ':')` should replace `.` with `:`.

Comment: @ChrisCharley did you read this problem? Sometimes there are no `PM`'s.